# All periods in string

Tags: algorithms

I want to find all the periods in a string. Moreover, I want to do it in a linear time and using a prefix function. I've noticed a pattern, that I want to generalize to an algorithm, though, unfortunately, I am not able to achieve *O(len(s))* time, so I'd like to get some clues, how to optimize the algorithm.

Here is what I came to. Consider a string and prefix function (just like in KMP algorithm):

**abababab**

**00121234**

I have noticed, that if we have a period of length *t*, then in indices *k * t* for natural *k >= 2* value of prefix function is *>=t*. The problem is that if I'd check all the prefixes of given string to satisfy this condition, then it would obviously take *O(len(s)^2)* time. What can be done to improve the speed of the algorithm?

Answer (score -2):

This is already way too late. But shouldn't this be $O(n \log{n})$? $n$ being $len(s)$. You are doing $\frac{n}{1} + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{3} + \cdots + \frac{n}{n} $ work, which integrates to $n \ln{n}$.

Prefix function precomputation is $O(n)$, so it wouldn't matter.